# Enable change tracking on all tables in snowflake cloud data warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How to enable change tracking = true on all tables in a schema in snowflake data warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running "ALTER TABLE … CHANGE_TRACKING = TRUE" for each table

Comment: can we write a stored procedure to alter all tables in a database?

Comment: Yes, just read the information schema for the tables you want, dynamically create the statements and run them